# DeploySourceNotFoundException on CloudBees

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I'am trying to deploy a war with jenkins of CloudBees. Sources are located on the Git repository of CloudBbees.
I can generate an deploy the war with the same sources code on my environment.
On the Jenkins of Cloudbees, the build is successful, but I got the following error at the deployment :

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ mysite ---
[INFO] Deleting /scratch/jenkins/workspace/Deploy/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- lutece-maven-plugin:3.0.2:site-assembly (default-cli) @ mysite ---
[INFO] Assembly-site lutece-site artifact...
[INFO] Exploding webapp in /scratch/jenkins/workspace/Deploy/target/mysite-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT...
[INFO] Copying webapp files
[INFO] Local configuration directory is /home/jenkins/lutece/conf/mysite
[WARNING] Local configuration directory /home/jenkins/lutece/conf/mysite does not exist
[INFO] Building jar: /scratch/jenkins/workspace/Deploy/target/mysite.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 28.993s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Mar 08 04:26:07 EST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/202M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /scratch/jenkins/workspace/Deploy/pom.xml to fr.paris.lutece/mysite/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/mysite-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
[cloudbees-deployer] Deploying as (jenkins) to the xxxx-xxxx account
[cloudbees-deployer] Deploying mysite
com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.exceptions.DeploySourceNotFoundException: Cannot find source for mysite
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine.perform(Engine.java:126)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:103)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:795)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:767)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1030)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:716)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1690)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:519)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:246)
Build step 'Deploy applications' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The application ID mysite exists and is found in the Jenkins configuration.
What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

In the logs, I can't see the "archiving" phase of the .war file so I believe that your .war was not properly packaged. Did you define it properly in your pom.xml?
Also, check in your workspace/target if the .war was generated.

Comment: Yes, the war is in the target dir : Building jar: /scratch/jenkins/workspace/Deploy/target/mysite.war. I verified it.